# Python / Django - If statement in template around extends

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to have a template that extends another conditionally.  Basically, when a variable called "ajax" is true I DO NOT want to have the template extend another.

```
{% if not ajax %}
    {% extends "/base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Any clues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to make {% extends '...' %} conditional? - Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380984/any-way-to-make-extends-conditional-django)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot do it like that. You can however set a variable and use that to choose the template to extend:

```
{% extends my_template %}
```

Then in python code you write something like:

```
if ajax:
    template_values['my_template'] = 'base_ajax.html'
else:
    template_values['my_template'] = 'base.html'
```

You may wish to [refer to the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#extends) for more information.

Comment: It is not the only way.

Comment: I don't see template_values in the documentation. I'm also not sure where to put the template_values code. So, I don't know how to implement the selected answer.

Comment: this answer, despite the check mark, does not give any context for the code it provides. where does it go? a view? somewhere else? the link to the documentation is also not helpful, as it only refers to usage of 'extends' and not the further code.

Answer (score 26):

While you may not wrap `extends` in logic blocks, since it must be the first tag if used, it can still accept variables, including filters. This should fit your purpose nicely:

```vhdl
{% extends ajax|yesno:"base_ajax.html,base.html" %}
{# stuff #}
```

Note: the `yesno` filter also accepts null values (`None`) as the third choice, and if you do not specify one (as in this case), it will fallback to converting it to `False` (i.e. it will return the second choice). This allows you to not specify the `ajax` variable in your template without breaking it.

---

Suggested by [user Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1798089/rafael):

```vhdl
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:"base_ajax.html,base.html" %}
{# stuff #}
```

This will only work if you are using a `RequestContext` context instead of a plain `Context` object and you have the `request` context processor enabled, or alternatively, if you insert the request object in your template context.

Comment: {% extends request.is_ajax|yesno.....%} works great and you don't need additional variables

Comment: As long as you are using a `RequestContext` instead of a regular `Context`.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the solution of the same problem and came with a bit better workaround than suggested by `Klaus Byskov Hoffmann`. It is better because you don't have to have 2 separate base templates for ajax and non-ajax requests and, which is more important, you don't have to define if statement that will define which base template to use in EACH controller.

In your case the solution would be:

**page.html**

```
{% extends "/base.html" %}
{% block body %}
    hello world
{% endblock body %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% if not ajax %}
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        LOGO and other stuff...

{% endif %}{% block body %}{% endblock body %}{% if not ajax %}

        FOOTER
    </body>
</html>
{% endif %}
```

So, base.html is always included but it prints its content only when `not ajax`.

UPDATE: This can be simplified by creating and adding a new ConextProcessor that will populate `ajax` context variable from the `HttpRequest.is_ajax()`, so you don't have to do anything extra in your controllers and templates at all.

Comment: yeah, this is a solution; however, i believe that separating the task via template file is cleaner than wrapping everything in a giant if....

Comment: it's not a really nice solution... better to put the not ajax in a layout.html and extend it

Comment: @GregL83 It's much easier to have ONE if statement in one template is much easier that writing `if` statement that will define the name of the base template in EACH controller. Also `ajax` can be defined using context processor from `HttpRequest.is_ajax()`. See updated answer.

Comment: @David天宇Wong please take a loot at updated answer and my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to "extend" a parent template, you can always create an empty file called null.html and extend that.  Kind of hacky, but easy to understand.

Comment: The problem is that `{% extends "/base.html" %}` should be the first line, you can't add if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but in case someone stumbles across this, I believe the best way to achieve your goal would be:
"views.py"

```
if ajax:
    request.session['ajax'] = 'ajax'
```

"base.html"

```
{% if 'ajax' in request.session %}
{% include "ajax.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

and in "ajax.html" you wouldn't use any {% extends %} or {% block %} tags since you won't be calling anything for "ajax.html" to extend onto the base. That will be taken care of by "include".