# Django Invalid block tag: 'else'

Tags: django, django-templates

Newbie question.

I need to extend to the user template if the user is authenticated otherwise extend the guest template.

I have the following code at the top my page.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% else %}
    {% extends 'guests/base.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

But then I get the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /events/
Invalid block tag: 'else'
```

If I don't use **extends** inside the condition then it works.  So i'm confuse what is wrong:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    user
{% else %}
    guest
{% endif %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python / Django - If statement in template around extends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043117/python-django-if-statement-in-template-around-extends)

Comment: I suggest you to separate the logic inside your view, not inside your template.