# Invalid block tag: 'else' - 'extends' inside a if statement

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to extends a template depending of the the existence of the 'custom_nav' variable:

```
{% if 'custom_nav' %}
    {% extends custom_nav %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "playexo/default_nav.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

But I get:

```
Invalid block tag on line 3: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

It is probably a dumb error but I can not figure it out, Iam wasting my time on it for 1h now...

I have searched for similar problem and it seems like an old one:
[Django Invalid block tag: 'else'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789434/django-invalid-block-tag-else)

Comment: use `include` instead of `extend`

Comment: @hansTheFranz include and extends are totally different beasts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. `extends` needs to be the first tag in a model. You should ensure that the variable always exists.

Comment: Quite restrictive. The error message isn't helping...
Thanks for the answers, I'll accept as soon as I can.