# Why does Django give this error: Invalid block tag on line 3: 'else'

Tags: django

I have the following Django template:

```
{% if request.is_ajax %}
  {% extends "ajax.html" %}
{% else %}
  {% extends "base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

When I render it I get the following error:

`Invalid block tag on line 3: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043117/python-django-if-statement-in-template-around-extends/19234016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{% extends %}` tag has to be the first line in your template if you are to use it at all. It is invalid syntax to do otherwise. You can however use a variable. I would do the following:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        base_template = "ajax.html"
    else:
        base_template = "base.html"
    ...
    context["base_template"] = base_template
    return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

Then in your template

```
{% extends base_template %}
...
```

An alternative approach if you don't want to add that logic to your view is to do the following:

```
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:"ajax.html,base.html" %}
...
```